# Что может при работе программы заставлять ее отвязываться от отладчика?

Tags: отладка, android, java, gps

Моя программа работает с gps и файловой системой. Работает свернутой в основном.. когда я произвожу манипуляции с телефоном.. например включаю или выключаю вайфай, запускаю еще программу которая использует gps.. такое чувство что перезапускается активити.. Как минимум вызывается его конструктор.. и после этого он сам отключается от отладчика.. то есть продолжает работу.. но отладчик говорить что "Disconnected".

Вот так привязываюсь к сервису локации

> loc_manager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
>   loc_manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,4000, 10, listener);

Вот так собственно с ним работаю

```
    synchronized public void onLocationChanged(android.location.Location location) 
    {


        long  diff =(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime() - start.getTime());
        if (max_time<diff)
        {
            max_time = diff;
            double x = location.getLongitude();
            double y = location.getLatitude();
            try 
            {
                DataRoutePoint t = new DataRoutePoint();
                t.time = diff;
                t.x_pos = x;
                t.y_pos = y;
                t.mark = (byte) 200;//no mark
                synchronized (out_file)
                {
                    out_file.writeObject(t);
                }
                waypoint_count++;
                txt = "Waypoints: "+Integer.toString(waypoint_count);
                txt_update.setText(txt);
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

когда Ваше приложение свернуто, система имеет полное (да, именно полное) право прибить приложение. И да, потом запустить, пересоздав активити. Понятно, что когда приложение перезапускается, то оно "отцепиться от отладчика".